# how to activate social sharing buttons on telescope

Tags: telescope

Does anyone know how to activate social sharing buttons on telescope? I have read all the telescope documentation but still no answer
Specifically which file do I edit? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Under the settings section under extra css add the following

```
.post-share {
    display: block; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it worked perfectly. I tried to create a custom post_share file with the hidden style removed but I couldn't get it to show.